# Is this assumption correct in proof of Weierstrass M-Test in Spivak's Calculus?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

The following is a theorem in Spivak's *Calculus*, Chapter 24 entitled "Uniform Convergence and Power Series"

> **Theorem (Weierstrass M-Test)**
>
> Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of functions defined on $A$ .
>
> Suppose $\{M_n\}$ is a sequence of numbers such that
> $$|f_n(x)|\leq M_n\ \ \text{ for all } x\in A$$
>
> Suppose that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty M_n$ converges.
>
> Then, for each $x\in A$ the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$
> converges (in fact, it converges absolutely) and
> $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ converges uniformly on $A$ to the
> function
>
> $$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$$

My question is about the assumption that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty M_n$ converges.

As written, this series can converge to any value.

**The proof of this theorem goes as follows**

Let $x\in A$ .

Consider the sequence $\{|f_n(x)|\}$ , each term of which is smaller than the corresponding term in the sequence $\{M_n\}$ .

Since $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty M_n$ converges, ie since $\{M_n\}$ is summable, then by the comparison test $\{|f_n(x)|\}$ is summable, ie $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty |f_n(x)|$ converges.

For all $x\in A$ we have

$$\left |f(x)-\sum\limits_{n=1}^N f_n(x)\right | = \left | \sum\limits_{n=N+1}^\infty f_n(x) \right |$$
$$\leq \sum\limits_{n=N+1}^\infty |f_n(x)|$$
$$\leq \sum\limits_{n=N+1}^\infty M_n$$

Since $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty M_n$ converges then the number $\sum\limits_{n=N+1}^\infty M_n$ can be made as small as desired by choosing $N$ sufficiently large.

In this last sentence, doesn't $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty M_n$ have to converge to 0?

Comment: Yes, for any series to converge, the sequence of its summands must converge to 0. This doesn't say anything about what the series itself converges to.

Comment: The last sentence in the OP had a typo. My question is about the convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty M_n$ not the underlying sequence. Doesn't the latter have to converge to 0 for the proof to work?

Comment: A series converges if and only if its “tails” converge to $0$. Look carefully at the starting point of that last series.

Comment: @TedShifrin I get that point. It's not clear why the tail converges to zero though.

Comment: That’s equivalent to convergence of the series. Write down what it means for the sequence of partial sums to converge. What you just wrote down is very false. $\implies$ is valid; $\impliedby$ is famously false.

Comment: We have a sequence $\{M_n\}$. We have a sequence of partial sums $\{s_n\}=\{ \sum_{i=1}^n M_n\}$. $\{s_n\}$ converges by assumption. The Cauchy criterion says that $\lim_{m,n\to\infty} (s_m-s_n)=\lim_{m,n\to\infty} (\sum_{i=n+1}^m M_i)=0$. Let $\epsilon>0$. There is an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n,m\geq N$ we have $|s_n-s_m|=|\sum_{i=n+1}^m M_i|<\epsilon$. If we pick $n=N+1$ then we have $|\sum_{i=N+1}^m M_i|<\epsilon$. We can remove the absolute value because $\{M_n\}$ is nonnegative.

Comment: Since this is true for all $m>N$ then by definition of limit we have $\lim_{m\to \infty} \sum_{i=N+1}^m M_i=0$ or $\sum_{i=N+1}^\infty M_i=0$.

Comment: Note that $\sum_{i = N +1}^\infty M_i \neq 0$ in general, but rather you can make it arbitrarily small (by picking $N$ bigger!), that is, $\sum_{i = N + 1}^\infty M_i < \varepsilon$ for $N$ large enough, not that it converges to 0. Making it as small as you want (but positive) is different than making it zero.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty M_n$ need not converge to 0, and in general note that it will not, since the condition $|f_n(x)| \leq M_n$ for all $x \in A$ for each $n$ implies each $M_n$ is non-negative, so you are taking a series of non-negative terms, and thus it will be positive if even one term is positive.

You can get an explicit counterexample in any common example of the application of the M-test, one common one is to prove a series like $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2 + n^2}$ converges, where we take $\{M_n\}_{n = 1}^\infty = \{\frac{1}{n^2}\}_{n = 1}^\infty$, and certainly $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty M_n \neq 0$.

Comment: But in the proof, one of the last steps is to say that $\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty M_n$ can be made as small as desired. Why doesn't this mean this series converges to zero?

Comment: @xoux Write this out for yourself explicitly for the geometric series $\sum (1/2)^n$.

Answer (score 1):

> In this last sentence, doesn't $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty M_n$ have to converge to 0?

But the series in that last sentence, that not start at $1$. It starts at $N+1$.  A series is convergent if and only if its tails can be small (this is simply a restatement of the fact that the sequence of partial sums has to be Cauchy). The fact that $\sum_nM_n<\infty$ (and this is a series of non-negative terms) implies by definition that given $\varepsilon>0$ you can find $N$ large enough such that $\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty M_n<\varepsilon$.

The above tells you absolutely nothing about the value of the series $\sum_nM_n$. In fact, and this is crucial to understanding convergence, whatever happens in the first however many terms you wants, is completely irrelevant to the existence of the limit. Only the behaviour "at infinity" matters.

---

**Edit: more details.**

By definition, that $\sum_nM_n<\infty$ means that the sequence $\{S_k\}$ of partial sums converges. A sequence of real numbers converges if and only if it is Cauchy. This means that given $\def\e{\varepsilon}\e>0$, there exists an index $n_0$ such for all $m>n>n_0$, $|S_m-S_n|<\e$. This we can rewrite as
$$
\e>|S_m-S_n|=\Big|\sum_{k=1}^mM_k-\sum_{k=1}^nM_k|=\Big|\sum_{k=n+1}^nM_k\Big|=\sum_{k=n+1}^mM_k.
$$
The last equality is justified because the terms are non-negative. As this holds for all $m$ and a monotone bounded sequence is convergent, this is equivalent with
$$
\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty M_n<\infty. 
$$

Comment: A sequence converges $\iff$ it is a Cauchy sequence $\iff |a_n-a_m|<\epsilon$ for $m,n$ above some $N$. Therefore, in the case of $\{M_n\}$ there is an $N$ such that the difference between any two terms can be made smaller than any $\epsilon>0$ for $n>N$. Since we are interested in partial sums of $\{M_n\}$, and the sequence of partial sums converges, then we can say the same thing about this sequence. The partial sums are all close to each other and to the value the sequence converges to. If we start removing initial terms from the sequence, the value converged to decreases.

Comment: But why does the tail converge to zero?

Comment: You already said it in your comment, so I'm not exactly sure what the question is. I have added some detail to the answer to see if it helps you.